# Re-Allocate 2D Array and delete old

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a Graph class which keeps track of a variety of vertex's and edges. When I add a vertex I want to check my `T* labels[]` dynamic array's capacity and double the capacity when it needs more room. When more space is needed, I will also be reallocating the 2D array so that I may include necessary information for that new vertex's edges. I do this in my `add_vertex` function by checking and comparing the number of vertices to the capacity, and calling `resize_edges()` and `resize_vertex()` when a condition is met.

First I call `resize_edges()` and begin allocating a bigger 2D array, I copy over the contents from the original array and then set the original array `edges[][]` to the new bigger array called `bool_new`, then I `delete [] bool_new`. Next, I do the same with my `labels[]`... When I delete `new_labels`, my program crashes.
Am I doing all of this correctly?

```
 template <typename T>
 void Graph<T>:: resize_edges()
 {
    bool ** bool_new;

    int new_cap = capacity*2;
    bool_new = new bool*[new_cap];

    for(int i = 0; i < new_cap ; i++)
    {
       bool_new[i] = new bool[new_cap];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
       for(int j = 0; j < capacity; j++)
       {
          bool_new[i][j] = edges[i][j];
       }
    }


   edges = bool_new;


   for(int i = 0 ; i < capacity ; i++) 
   {
       delete[] bool_new[i]; 
   }
   delete [] bool_new;
 }

 template <typename T>
 void Graph<T>::resize_vertex()
 {
     T* new_labels;
     int new_cap = capacity*2;
     new_labels = new T[new_cap];

     for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i ++)
     {
         new_labels[i] = labels[i];
     }

   labels = new_labels;
   delete [] new_labels;
}
```

Comment: My advice is *don't*. Whenever you think "dynamic array" of any kind, the next thought should always be [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Even for such a special case as `std::vector<bool>` is.

Comment: So are your recommending I use a vector<T> for my labels array instead?

Comment: For *all* your arrays.

Comment: Both functions allocate a new lot of memory, and then release it.    After `resize_edges()`, `edges` is a dangling reference.   After `resize_vertex()`, `labels` is a dangling reference.   The original dynamically allocated arrays, in both cases, are leaked (assuming they were previously created correctly).

Comment: Think abstract. That is hard and that is the key. What [Graph design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) are you coding?  It seems you have "dropped" to quickly from design to coding. std lib has moe than enough abstractions to successfully design and implement the "graph". But essentially we are tapping in the dark ... we see no complete but short, code of yours. And if it would **also** be online that would be one feasible questions/answers, session for you.

Answer (score 0):

A major problem with the code you show is that you don't free the old memory that was allocated, and that you free the new memory you just allocated.

In the `resize_edges` function you do

```
edges = bool_new;
```

which will make you loose the original memory that `edges` points to, which of course leads to a memory leak.

But what's worse is that after that you free the memory that you just allocated, meaning that `edges` will become an invalid pointer immediately.

Before the assignment you need to free the *old* memory, and after the assignment you need to *keep* the new memory.

Another problem is that you don't update `capacity`.

You have the same problem in the `resize_vertex` function.

Comment: my capacity is updated in the add_vertex function afterwards. I was doing everything in the same functions called resize but thought maybe I should seperate them .

Comment: @Levitate That's why we really need to see a [mcve], otherwise we don't have all the information.

Comment: I see that now. I am new to this, still getting the hang of it. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Thank You. That was a good refresher. I now have this function to handle it all.

```
template <typename T>
 void Graph<T>:: resize()
{
    bool ** bool_new;
    T* new_labels;
    new_labels = new T[capacity*2];
    int new_cap = capacity*2;
   bool_new = new bool*[new_cap];

   for(int i = 0; i < new_cap ; i++)
   {
       bool_new[i] = new bool[new_cap];
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < capacity; j++)
      {
          bool_new[i][j] = edges[i][j];
      }
    }

   for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i ++)
   {
       new_labels[i] = labels[i];
   }

  for(int i = 0 ; i < capacity; i++)
  {
         delete[] edges[i];
  }

  delete [] edges;
  delete [] labels;

  edges = bool_new;
  labels = new_labels;
   capacity *= 2;
  }
```